3.3V To 24V Power ON/OFF Switch
I'm quite of a beginner with electronics.
I’m building a robot powered by 4x 24V car batteries connected in parallel. I need a power switch circuit that:
Powers on the system when a momentary push button is held for 3 seconds.
Keeps the system powered until the button is held again for 3 seconds to turn it off.
The requirements are:
The system voltage is 24V, and the batteries are capable of delivering high currents.
The circuit should prevent accidental activation or deactivation with brief button presses.
Currently, I just have a main switch with a relay to hold the power on. Any suggestions what I should do? Tutorials etc..

A 3v3 schmitt trigger sharpens the edges to Clk input of 4013 D-flip-flop.
Bat54 (or BAT46) schottky diode quickly discharges the capacitor after PB becomes released to be ready for next press.

